# Symfony Bundle Inheritance - Extending an Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm extending the functionality of an existing Symfony-based application and have found that additional bundles and using bundle inheritance has worked well to customise the functionality.

I've now found myself wanting to inherit from an existing bundle to customise its functionality but I also need to add some additional entities and extend the existing ones. The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/bundles/override.html#entities-entity-mapping) suggests it might not be possible to extend an existing one since the entity is not a mapped superclass.

Is there anything I can do in this case? I basically want to retain the vast majority of the functionality of the existing bundle, but be able to collect more data.

EDIT:

I've looked into [Doctrine inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) and everything seems to require I have access to the top-level class in order to extend it. Which isn't ideal, as I'd like to keep that class the same.

Comment: It seams that third party has bad architecture. Please read about composition over inheritance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance. There is no warranty for bundles that comes free from community